# What is a better way to use less code to hide and display select menu content? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

**UPDATE** The option values are not incremental, does that matter? Eg. one option could be apples, the next could be dog

I have multiple drop down menus with multiple options and every time I select an option I display different information but in order to hide it to display a different option's information, I have to compare the current option's value and if it matches, hide it, then show the new option's information.

As an example:

drop-down select menu

```
<select name="name_of_select_menu" onchange="showContent(value);">
<option value="">label option</option>
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="dog">dog</option>
<option value="shoes">shoes</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showContent($i) {
if($i=="apple"){
document.getElementById('apple').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('dog').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('shoes').style.display = "none";
}
if($i=="apple"){
document.getElementById('apple').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('dog').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('shoes').style.display = "none";
}
if($i=="apple"){
document.getElementById('apple').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('dog').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('shoes').style.display = "inline-block";
}

}
```

content to be displayed

```
<div class="content">
<div id="apple">
<p>
I am an apple
</p>
</div>
<div id="dog">
<p>
I am a dog
</p>
</div>
<div id="shoes">
<p>
I am a pair of shoes
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this can become a lot... I have like 20 options for one menu... 19 things to check if open and close, then open the actual one that you want to see.

Comment: You should prepend your variables by `$` if, and only if, it's a `jQuery` object. Here, it's a string.

Comment: @D4V1D this is not jquery code . its javascript code only

Comment: I see that. But my suggestion is still valid. And you tagged `jQuery` so allow me to point that out.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I took out the jQuery tags

Comment: @janicehoplin Do the elements that you're trying to hide/show have a common class name? Or a shared parent element?

Comment: @nbrooks There are several select menus, the option values are not incremental, they are arbitrary eg. random strings, I'm not sure if it would be better to use incremented options or just incremented integers. Each content that shows up per option selected has its own unique id otherwise it is simply a div element. They are all under a single class eg. the content window

Comment: @janicehoplin  [id^=option] . this code hide all ids which start with option. no need to add any increment value here

Comment: @janicehoplin  i have added working demo in my answer

Comment: @janicehoplin : Do you have Id attribute on elements? Can you share the relevant HTML too

Comment: @janicehoplin can you please add your html code if ids have different names other then option prefix then code will not work . provide some HTML code or use common class name for all that ids ..

Comment: @ K K, the elements I'm assuming you mean content, have their own id's which I then use to change the css display property. I don't know what you are looking for regarding the relevant HTML, I have shown the primary parts of the code but using arbitrary but I will update the question to further elaborate, thank you for all of your efforts

Comment: @janicehoplin If your IDs are arbitrary strings, none of the answers which rely on the word "option" being in the ID will work. The attribute selectors (e.g. `[id^="option"]`) are literally saying the ID will start with or contains the word "option". I did update my post below to workaround that, FYI.

Comment: @janicehoplin Check the updated solution which is according to the html you have added in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code.  Check working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/5t3t5Lyn/4/)

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content div').hide();
    $(document).on('change','select[name="name_of_select_menu"]',function(){
       $('.content div').hide();
       $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); 
    }); 
 });
```

HTML

```
<select name="name_of_select_menu">
 <option value="">label option</option>
 <option value="apple">apple</option>
 <option value="dog">dog</option>
 <option value="shoes">shoes</option>
</select>

   <div class="content">
    <div id="apple">
     <p>
       I am an apple
      </p>
     </div>
     <div id="dog">
       <p>
       I am a dog
       </p>
    </div>
    <div id="shoes">
     <p>
      I am a pair of shoes
     </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I see that your demo works however I updated my question that I am not using incremental options, they are arbitrary strings, I can't seem to get it to work... thank you for all of your efforts so far

Comment: @janicehoplin can you please add your html code if ids have different names other then option prefix then code will not work . provide some HTML code or use common class name for all that ids ..

Comment: I don't know why this, K K and nbrooks's answers are not working... the two divs that I have are automatically shown despite being initiated as display: none;

Comment: your demo works, it's not working for my code, do I need to declare the id's in the css area eg. #apple { display: none; } ? that's what I usually do when using display to hide/show content

Comment: @janicehoplin you want to hide all divs when page load ? then base on selection you want to show div? right ?

Comment: Yes, I don't want anything displayed initially, only the select menus, then selecting an option from a drop down menu displays that content, the next selection of any menu's option, hides the previous and displays the selected option's content. I know this is a pain... I'm okay with a lot of code for now, this is just a personal project but I will implement what you have written along with others in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your determined effort. I would also like to thank others for their input. When I can I will up people's answers / input but without points I'm not able to. Perhaps after selecting this as an answer I can upvote. Thanks again.

Comment: I think my problem may be that I am using onchange within the select input

Comment: @janicehoplin  happy to help you . first thing in your question is you are use core javascript. using jquery your code become very small .. no issue with your on change event it will work fine . i just show you how jquery work with onchange event

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

```
function showContent(i) {
    $(".content>div").hide(); //for arbitrary keywords.
    $('div#' + i).css("display", "inline-block");
}
```

Change the function to:

```
function showContent(i) {
    $("[id*=option]").hide();
    $('#' + i).css("display", "inline-block");
}
```

[Read more about attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: the options are not incremented, they are different words, does that matter?

Comment: If the ID attribute contains "option" word, it will not matter and the code will work fine. Basically, $("[id*=option]") selects all the elements whose id contains "option" string in it.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't hide them, perhaps I did something wrong

Comment: For this to work, you should have "option" string anywhere in the ID's of the elements. If "option" is missing or replaced then it will not work. So make sure that the elements which you want to target must have "option" string in their id.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, you can write:

```
function showContent(i)
  document.getElementById(i).style.display = "inline-block";
  $("select[name=name_of_select_menu]").find("option").not("option[id=="+i+"]").hide();
}
```

Comment: The OP's code isn't trying to hide `<option>` elements, nor is that even possible through css, AFAIK...

Answer (score 1):

[***jsFiddle (Updated)***](http://jsfiddle.net/q3pdopsn/1/)

You can simplify this in a few different ways. Move the change handler out of the HTML and bind to the DOM element directly from your JS. Then capture the value of the form element dynamically, and use that to determine which element to show.

Since you're toggling the visibility of the elements, you need a way to hide all of the elements at once. You can do this using`$('.content > div').hide()` to hide all of the elements and then `$('#yourId').show()` to show a specific one.

HTML:

```
<select name="name_of_menu">
  <option value="">label option</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>
```

JS (using jQuery):

```
$(function () {
    $('[name="name_of_menu"]').change(function () {
        $('.content > div').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).css("display", "inline-block");
    });
});
```